# What does (-) mean when defining a language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I have a language defined as L = {0, 1}$^*$ - {$0^n$$1^n$ : n >= 0}.

I'm not sure what the hyphen's (-) function is.

The alphabet is not defined in this homework problem so I do not know if it is a character or an operator and I cannot find a definition for it in my textbook or online.

Comment: It is a minus sign, i.e., relative complement.  Your $L$ is all sequences except those which are $n$ $0$s followed by $n$ $1$s, any $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much your answer just made it click for me and I understand completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a minus sign, i.e., relative complement. Your L is all sequences except those which are n 0s followed by n 1s, any n. – user10354138 19 mins ago